# Remove all non-word char except if &amp; or &apos; pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to clean a string of all non-word character except when it is & i.e. pattern might be like `&[\w]+;`

For example:

```
abc; => abc
abc &amp; => abc &amp;
abc& => abc
```

if i use `string.replaceAll("\W","")`  it removes `;` and `'&'` too from second example which I don't want.

Can using negative look-ahead in this problem could give a quick solution regex pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I really like the question. Now, what you want could not be done with a single `replaceAll`, because for that, we would need a `negative look-behind` with variable length, which is not allowed. If it was allowed, then it would not have been that difficult.

Anyways, since single `replaceAll` is no option here, you can use a little hack here. Like first replacing the last `semi-colon` of you `entity reference`, with some character sequence, which you are sure won't be there in the rest of the string, like `XXX` or anything. I know this is not correct, but you sure can't help it out.

So, here's what you can try:

```
String str = "a;b&c &amp;";

str  = str.replaceAll("(&\\w+);", "$1XXX")
          .replaceAll("&(?!\\w+?XXX)|[^\\w&]", "")
          .replaceAll("(&\\w+)XXX", "$1;");

System.out.println(str);
```

**Explanation:**

- The first replaceAll, replaces the pattern like `&amp;` with `&ampXXX`, or any other sequence replaced for last `;`.
- The second replaceAll, replaces any `&` not followed by `\\w+XXX`, or any `non-word, non &` character. This will replace all the `&'s` which are not a part of `&amp;` kind of pattern. Plus, also replaces any other non-word character.
- The third replaceAll, re-replaces `XXX` with `;`, to create back `&amp;` from `&ampXXX`

---

And to make it easier to understand, you can rather use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes and I would always prefer to use them whenever the replacement criteria is complex.

```
String str = "a;b&c &amp;";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&\\w+;|[^\\w]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    if (!match.matches("&\\w+;")) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
    } else {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, match);
    }
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This one is similar to @Eric's code, but is a generalization over it. That one will only work for `&amp;` of course if it was improved to remove `NullPointerException` that is thrown in it.

Comment: Nice answer, although at the beginning I was wanting for an more compact solution.

Comment: @dreamcrash. It could have been little compact, had the variable length look-behind were allowed in Java Regex. In which case the replacement would have been as straight as: `str.replaceAll("(?<!&\\w+);|&(?!\\w+-)|[^\\w;&]", "");`

Comment: @dreamcrash. AFAIK, some regex engines do allow variable length look-behinds, but I don't really remember which are they.

Comment: Thanks, for the response, I wasn't criticizing the solution by it self. It just every time I see regex answer the question then to be simple and elegant. Really need to learn how to work with regex :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do this using a simple String.replaceAll.  You should probably use a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to loop through the matches, effectively doing a manual search and replace.  Something like the following code should do the trick.

```
public String replaceString(String origString) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&(\w+);|[^\w]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(origString);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group().startsWith("&") && !matcher.group(1).equals("amp")) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group());
        } else {
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
        }
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a negative lookahead like this:

```
string.replace(/&(?!\w+;)/ig, '');
```

Which replaces all & not followed by a word characters ending with a semicolon.

EDIT (Java):

```
string.replaceAll("/&(?!\w+;)/i", '');
```

Comment: Haha, I did read "javascript"... so something close to my edit should work in Java.